# Search through a map list and return multiple results

Tags: scala, list

I am currently a student studying and have just finished a piece of work, however I have misinterpreted the question. I was suppose to get the current "most recent" price for each data, however I created it so that I searched individually for each data.
For instance, I would press 1 in the menu option and enter "SK1" and the average result would show, I need this modified so when I press 1 in the menu option, I do not enter anything and have ALL of the averages displayed.

Here is my current code to search for a data and return the results. I need to return all data not only the one searched for.;

p.s. Mapdata is a "Map(String, List[Int])"

```
//5 - Show Current data Level
  def handleFive(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowSingleData(currentDataLevel)
    true
  }

// Returns a single result, not a list
  def mnuShowSingleData(data: (String) => (String,Int)) = {
    print("data > ")
    val data2 = data(readLine)
    println(s"${data2._1}: ${data2._2}")
  }

  //Show last element in the list, most current
  def currentDataLevel (data: String): (String, Int) = {
    (data, mapdata.get (data).map(findLast(_)).getOrElse(0))
  }
```

I understand what im doing and how to search for individual results, just not sure how to modify it to search through and return all data last elements.

More accurately worded;

> Given a Map[String, List[Int]], how do I produce a Map[String, Int]
>   where for each key in the input, the resulting value would be the last
>   item in the corresponding value, or 0 if the value is an empty list?
>   For example, for this input:

Comment: your question is incomprehensible. Try giving a concrete example of input and expected output, and remove all irrelevant information ("I would press 1 in the menu option ..." - how is this relevant? What menu? What are the "averages"?)

Comment: How so? This is what it does, this is what I am trying to get it to do? Currently I can search for 1 list value, and return 1 values last element. I need to be able to return all last elements without a search, @TzachZohar

Comment: Oh, so you want "all the _last_ elements"? Read your post again and see that even _that_ isn't written there, and 90% of what _is_ written is completely unnecessary. Please, help people help you by providing all the necessary information, and only the necessary information.

Comment: @TzachZohar sorry about that, I thought id explained that what I have is the ability to search for individual last elements and return it. What I NEED is all last elements of all data lists returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll rephrase the question into what I think it asks:

> Given a `Map[String, List[Int]]`, how do I produce a `Map[String, Int]` where for each key in the input, the resulting value would be the last item in the corresponding value, or `0` if the value is an empty list? For example, for this input:

```
val m = Map("a" -> List(1,2,3), "b" -> List(4,5), "c" -> List[Int]())
```

> I would want the following output: `Map("a" -> 3, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 0)`

If that's the question - here's the answer:

```
 m.mapValues(_.lastOption.getOrElse(0))
```

**EDIT**: incorporated in the OP's code:

```
def mnuShowSingleData() = {
  val current = currentDataLevel()
  // just a suggestion, you can obviously play around with the way this is printed:
  print(s"data > ${current.mkString(", ")}") 
}

def currentDataLevel(): Map[String, Int] = {
  mapdata.mapValues(_.lastOption.getOrElse(0))
}

// prints: data > a -> 3, b -> 5, c -> 0
```

Comment: Is there anyway you can incorporate that into my question code? I understand how to find the last values, I'm struggling with modifying my code to show multiple results instead of one. What you have shown is what I require, but Im not sure how to implement it. @TzachZohar

Comment: Done, hope it helps

Comment: `min` and `max` are not supported for empty lists. If you can guarantee none of the lists are empty, you can simply do `mapdata.mapValues(_.min)` . Otherwise, you can perform the reduction yourself using `reduceOption`, for example: `mapdata.mapValues(_.reduceOption(Math.min).getOrElse(0))`